# I have to remove trim from query to tune performance of data fetching

Tags: sql

I have a query like :

```
select *
from PERSON
where trim(person_name) = trim(Filter(name))
  and trim(person_id) = trim(filter(ID)) .
```

Here i have to remove trim to improve performance , is there any alternative?

Comment: Tag the DBMS product which are you using (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server ... etc.). "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Do you have any leading blanks?

Comment: Yes, the alternative is to do one time update of your columns to trim off the unwanted leading/trailing whitespace.  Then, you can compare in the `WHERE` clause directly without using functions.

Comment: Yes , that's what creating a problem . If i am removing trim , I couldn't able to fetch particular column data

Comment: do u need to use trim in filter (ID) ?

Comment: Yes , because ID in column are coming with different length . So if ID is coming in shorter length are containing space and also it's using VARCHAR(60)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**: Based on your problem and comments: 
I think that there is not any solution.

**But my solution**: you have a **trade-off** between **performance** and **redundancy**.

1. If you persisting to have untrimmed data in the database,
2. and performance is **so important** in your project

you can create 4 other column and put the trimmed of each equivalent column to them with one update query.

So you should manage you all select and insert queries with these 4 additional columns.